# No mixin named nb-install

Tags: css, angular, scss-mixins, nebular

i am using angular5, getting the 'No mixin named nb-install' error when executing npm start or serve

```
Module build failed:
undefined
        ^
      No mixin named nb-install

Backtrace:
        stdin:13
      in E:\mrb_bugfixes\bottledepot\src\app\@theme\styles\styles.scss (line 13, column 10)
```

Following is the file named 'styles.scss' i am executing

```
@import 'themes';

// framework component themes (styles tied to theme variables)
@import '~@nebular/theme/styles/globals';
@import '~@nebular/auth/styles/all';

// loading progress bar theme
@import './pace.theme.scss';

// install the framework and custom global styles

@include nb-install() {

// framework global styles
@include nb-theme-global();
@include nb-auth-global();

// loading progress bar
@include ngx-pace-theme();

.custom-control .custom-control-indicator {
border-radius: 50%; // TODO: quickfix for 
https://github.com/akveo/nebular/issues/275
}
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a long time. i have found to install this dependencies.....

```
npm install --save @nebular/theme @angular/cdk @angular/animations
```